# IntegrationAccountNotReady when transforming xml in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm currently trying Azure Logic Apps and Integration Services.

I always get an *IntegrationAccountNotReady* error message, when I'm trying to transform a XML-File with Azure Logic Apps and an Azure Integration Account.

The message says I should try it again later. However, I waited 5 days with no success.

My Logic App and the Integration Account are successfully connected.

Here is my flow:

1. On File Changed Trigger (One Drive) - Works as expected
2. Tranform XML - The error is raised

Is there any easy solution to solve this problem?

Regards,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

I tried it again and again. Finally it worked - without any changes in my configuration, integration service or logic app. Strange...

Sorry I got no better answer to this...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Refreshing the Resources in Dashboard solved it immediately.